# Is there a way to modify a value in an array during execution using App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have designed various spreadsheets that are all interconnected in order to automate the scheduling of tasks for different divisions. however as the system has grown so has my function run times due to the increased data to go through, analyze and modify. I have traced the issue back to fact that i have nested loops that with an if statement re-initialize an array after modifying the sheet in order to continue with the new values in the array for referencing by the if statement.

I've searched the web and the google references but have so far come up dry for an answer. I am an amateur programmer so I acknowledge the fact that i may have missed what i was looking simply because i'm green and still learning So my apologies if this is a silly question

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastC = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var valueA = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastR, lastC).getValues();
  var value3 = 1;
  for(i=0; i<lastR-1; i++){
    var value1 = valueA[i][0];
    for(j=0; j<lastR-1; j++){
      for(k=0; k<lastR-1; k++){
        var value2 = valueA[k+1][j];
        if(value1 <= value2){
          var valueDest = sheet.getRange(k, j-1);
          valueDest.setValue(value3);
          value3 = value3 +1;
          valueA = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastR, lastC).getValues();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please excuse any mistakes this code is hastily written in order to give an idea of what i am trying to accomplish

it is the last line of the if statement limiting the execution speed

Is there a way to modify the value in the array with code rather than calling the array from the sheet over and over again in order to speed up the execution

Comment: `valueA[k+1][j]=value3` ?

Comment: that awkward moment you realize the answers been staring you in the face thank you so much just revised some of the code works like a charm i cant believe it was so simple and i completely over looked that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: You could replace this: `var valueA = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastR, lastC).getValues();` with this: `var valueA = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`